# Yum just stopped woiking and gives error

Tags: linux, centos, yum

## yum -y update

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     |  22 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
mysql-connectors-community                               | 2.5 kB     00:00
mysql-tools-community                                    | 2.5 kB     00:00
mysql56-community                                        | 2.5 kB     00:00

14: HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please create a bug on https://bugs.centos.org/

One of the configured repositories failed (RHEL 7 - RPMforge.net - dag),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable rpmforge

 4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=rpmforge.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

--- I get this error anytime I try using yum

Comment: why do you have a repo added that is no longer available? for one and second, whenever yum on my rhel can't find one repo it just skips that repo and goes to others, unless that repo is needed for a package.

Comment: Isn't this slightly OFF TOPIC? This has nothing to do with programming as far as I can tell.

Comment: It is not about being programming or not. I just can't find a way to fix it and I am new to using Linux

Comment: @jgr208 How do I remove the repo?

Comment: This question may be better suited for SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I fix it by navigating to the faulty repository in the yum repository directory

cd  /etc/yum.repos.d

Then you can list all repos by using

ls

Then you can remove using
yum remove [repos-name]